# How Count or Total number of row after on groupby in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hy I have 2 tables

**1.application**

```
id | name    | status
====================
1  | morvick | complete
2  | siti    | prosess
3  | boby    | complete
```

**2.application_test**

`id | application_id  | test_id | result`
`======================================`
`1 | 1  |              1 |       70`
`2 | 1  |              2 |       80`
`3 | 1  |              3 |       90`
`4 | 2  |              1 |       60`
`5 | 2  |              2 |       80`
`6 | 2  |              3 |       70`
`7 | 3  |              1 |       90`
`8 | 3  |              2 |       70`
`9 | 3  |              3 |       60`
`10| 3  |              4 |       80`

Myquery Like This :

```
SELECT test_id, 
SUM(IF(app.status='complete',apt.result,0)) AS complete_sum, 
SUM(IF(app.status='process',apt.result,0)) AS process_sum  
FROM application_test AS apt 
JOIN application AS app ON app.id=apt.application_id 
GROUP BY apt.test_id
```

and to be like this :
`test_id | SUM(result = complete) | SUM(result = proses) |`
`1       | 90         | 50`
`2       | 80         | 40`
`3       | 90         | 60`
`4       | 80         | 70`

My quetion is: how I can get the total or Count number of rows after I do a query GROUPBY.. ? For example, **4 total number**

Comment: Can you add an sql fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subquery,

```
Select *, Count(*) as total_rows From(
SELECT test_id, 
SUM(IF(app.status='complete',apt.result,0)) AS complete_sum, 
SUM(IF(app.status='process',apt.result,0)) AS process_sum  
FROM application_test AS apt 
JOIN application AS app ON app.id=apt.application_id 
GROUP BY apt.test_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
SELECT (select count(*) from application_test) as total_row, 
test_id, 
SUM(IF(app.status='complete',apt.result,0)) AS complete_sum, 
SUM(IF(app.status='process',apt.result,0)) AS process_sum  
FROM application_test AS apt 
JOIN application AS app ON app.id=apt.application_id 
GROUP BY apt.test_id
```

Comment: yah, i mean the total_row = count per group, because you already used group by apt.test_id, the count(*) will count the total per group

Comment: Hy, Webster I think This is not total rows, but count per group, My quetion is Total rows but thanks for your answer

Comment: ahh i got ya, so you want the total rows of what table? please see my edited post